# Do Linux capabilities partition the possible privileged operations?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-capabilities

More precisely, are there any operations for which more than one capability could be used to give a process the necessary permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

I would say the overarching *model* is that each operation is guarded by a single capability. However, there are certainly exceptions. At a glance through the kernel/ directory, I quickly found one example. The usermodehelper `sysctl` handler requires both CAP_SETPCAP and CAP_SYS_MODULE capabilities in order to update its settings.

Another factor to consider: capability checks are sprinkled throughout the kernel code, including numerous drivers. A driver writer can choose to check for capabilities in whatever way they deem best so there could well be one that requires the caller to hold multiple capabilities.

Finally, there are numerous other cases where a single operation might potentially *use* more than a single capability even though it fundamentally requires only one. For example, consider a system call that requires a capability as a base but also takes a pathname argument for some operation. I found as example: `pr_ctl` system call with option `PR_SET_MM` and sub-option `PR_SET_MM_EXE_FILE`. This call requires `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` foundationally. However, it also requires certain permissions to the file. If the calling user doesn't have the right credentials to access the file, however, that permission can be overridden if the caller has `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` capability.

Comment: In hindsight my question seems kind of stupid considering there probably isn't a notion of an 'operation' in the kernel. As you seem to have guessed I meant to ask whether any syscall could require more than one capability, but you have answered that, thanks